# Where does the Traits/UI notification exception handler put its log file?

Tags: python, enthought, traitsui

I'm getting this, from a Traits/UI application running under Windows7Pro:

```
> Exception occurred in traits notification handler. Please check the
> log file for details.
```

**Where can I find the log file that it speaks of?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If your application has configured a log file, the traits logging will be there by default, otherwise I think there will be no log file. It's simple to configure; see https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file

2) But the info in that file might not actually be very useful for debugging, unless you take additional steps. See http://traits.readthedocs.io/en/latest/traits_user_manual/debugging.html#re-raising-exceptions-in-change-handlers